# How to create generic class to map A collection<propertyname,message> with a simple dto for validation

Tags: c#, generics

I have a collection of string, string where say `propertyname` and a message to bind with that property is store eg

```
class Rules
{
    public string PropertyName {get;set;}
    public string Message {get;set;}
}


obj1=new Rule{PropertyName="ClientId", Message="Client Id is mandatory"};
obj2=new Rule{PropertyName="ClientName", Message="Client Name is mandatory"};
```

similarly many such object as collection.
Now I have one plain DTO class say

```
class Client
{
    public string ClientId {get;set;}
    public string ClientName {get;set;}
    ........
}
```

Now I want to write a generic class which can apply those property with message as mandatory field on say Client class where property matches in collection.

Comment: You're going to have to start us off here I'm afraid - this isn't a code writing service.

Comment: Please see the [MSDN page on generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx).